# Can I use VS 2008 Standard to publish reports to SSRS/SQL server 2008?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm new to SSRS and I've been using Report Builder to create reports.  But I understand Visual Studio is a better environment and/or would like to use BIDS -- problem is, I cannot find our SQL server DVD or key (which I assume I need for something), but I would like to know if I can at least use Visual Studio Standard on my PC to create reports and publish them to SSRS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

BIDS is a Visual Studio plug-in.

Comment: Is the plugin a free download? I'm having trouble finding it.  I thought it had to be installed off the SQL Server DVD which is problematic since I do not know where it (or the key) is.  If it is a free plugin, that would be great!

Comment: @David: look at this: you should be able to download (applies to 2005 and 2008) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx

Comment: That articles talked about Express and I have standard.  Anyway, I'm going to try installing BIDS using SQL Server installer I downloaded.  I'll use the Evaluation option until the IT director finds the license for me.

Comment: @david: this has the tools included. That is, BIDS. BIDS is edition independent.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That is plenty of information to get me started.  Have a good day!